# python декоратор возвращаемых значений в json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Нужен декоратор применимый к любым функциям, возвращающих значения, и преобразующих их в *JSON*. У меня вышел такой только применимый к уже имеющимся значениям, никак не могу додуматься как доделать чтобы он принимал любые значения с консоли. Подскажите хотя бы куда копать

```
import functools
import json



def to_json(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return json.dumps(func())

    return wrapped


@to_json
def get_data():
    return {
        'data': 42
    }


get_data()
```

Comment: lдолжен возвращать  '{"data": 42}'

Comment: нужно добавить обработку ошибок, наподобие конструкции select case. Т.к. для строки, массива, объекта - разные способы обработки

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [35]: def to_json(func):
    ...:     @functools.wraps(func)
    ...:     def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
    ...:         return json.dumps(func(*args, **kwargs))  # <-- обратите внимание на вызов `func(...)`
    ...:     return wrapped
    ...:

In [36]: @to_json
    ...: def get_data(parm):
    ...:     return {
    ...:         'data': parm
    ...:     }
    ...:

In [37]: get_data(1)
Out[37]: '{"data": 1}'

In [38]: get_data({'key':'value'})
Out[38]: '{"data": {"key": "value"}}'

In [39]: get_data([1,2,3])
Out[39]: '{"data": [1, 2, 3]}'

In [40]: get_data({'key':'value', 'nested':{'list':[1,2,3,4]}})
Out[40]: '{"data": {"key": "value", "nested": {"list": [1, 2, 3, 4]}}}'
```